# Need Oracle error message translated

Tags: java, oracle11g, internationalization

I have a use case in my web app which checks for the validity of an SQL query and if invalid, displays the Oracle error message received. The problem is whatever the browser locale may be, the message displayed is in English. The message is given below:

*ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement*

I have been told that I need to use an Oracle package called G$_NLS_UTILITY which takes a parameter p_locale and sets NLS_LANG to its value. I tried this:

```
`public static setLocaleInDatabase(sql) {

    def userlocale
    try {
        userlocale = LocaleContextHolder?.getLocale()?.toString()?.replaceAll('-','_')
        sql.call("""{call g\$_nls_utility.p_set_nls(${userlocale})}""")
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug "There was an exception while setting nls for locale ${userlocale}:" + e.getMessage()
    }

}`
```

Can someone please illustrate its use or suggest any other method to get the Oracle error in the browser's language?

Comment: The message language is from the database connection NLS_LANG, from the web app server's locale, not the browser's. If you're using a connection pool you'd need to set the session language (via `alter session`) every time you got a connection from the pool, assuming your users' browsers can have any locale. That package seems of be part of 'Banner', which matches the 8.7.5 comment; are you actually using that software?

Comment: I tried the alter statement but to no avail- sql.execute("alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE='SPANISH'"). If you look at my code, I'm trying to feed the browser locale to the 'userLocale' variable and then passing this variable to my sql call for nls_utility package. Could you please shed some light on this package and how to use it?

Comment: @AlexPoole- Apologies for the confusion,'Banner' is something specific to my company's product, this doesn't affect anything here. G$_NLS_UTILITY is an oracle package but there's not a single example on the internet on its usage.

Comment: It is not a standard Oracle package, it's from third-party software ([this is the only reference I found](https://inet.mountsaintvincent.edu/banner/bandocs/BanSecure/bdoc8x/general8x/Banner_General_Release_Guide_8.7.5.pdf)). I imagine it's just doing an `alter session` internally anyway. Your command should work - and then get "ORA-00900: sentencia SQL no válida" - so are you sure you're calling that and then running the invalid statement in the same database session?

Comment: It is relevant because the package is part of that software product. You haven't said what happens when you call it; does the log cay the call failed or worked? If it worked then you may still have multiple sessions - setting the language in one, and then trying to run the invalid statement in another.

Comment: I got your point. Yes I'm calling that and then running the invalid statement in the same database session

Comment: OK, then what is `sql`, and what is its `call` method - is that your own class with a wrapper around a JDBC `prepareCall/execute` section, and if so is that changing the session or even starting a new session?

Comment: sql is a connection object which will be passed as an argument to the afor ementioned method which will be called immediately after defining 'sql'.